# Get secrets for GCP deployments from KMS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager, google-cloud-kms, google-secret-manager

I want to deploy a Cloud VPN tunnel in GCP using Deployment Manager

I set up a deployment script using Python for this and I don't want the shared secret for the VPN tunnel in plain text in my configuration.

So I tried to include the secret encrypted via [KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/) and then perform a call to the KMS in the python script to get the plain text secret.

The python code to decrypt the secret looks like this:

```
import base64
import googleapiclient.discovery 

def decryptSecret(enc_secret,context):
    """ decrypts the given Secret via KMS"""

    # KMS Configuration
    KEY_RING     = <Key Ring>
    KEY_ID       = <Key>
    KEY_LOCATION = REGION
    KEY_PROJECT  = context.env['project'],

    # Creates an API client for the KMS API.
    kms_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudkms', 'v1')

    key_name = 'projects/{}/locations/{}/keyRings/{}/cryptoKeys/{}'.format(
       KEY_PROJECT, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_RING, KEY_ID)

    crypto_keys =  kms_client.projects().locations().keyRings().cryptoKeys()

    request = crypto_keys.decrypt(
            name=key_name,
            body={'ciphertext': enc_secret})
    response = request.execute()
    plaintext = base64.b64decode(response['plaintext'].encode('ascii'))

    return plaintext
```

But if I deploy this code I just get the following error message from deployment manager:

```
Waiting for update [operation-<...>]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1517326129267-5640004f18139-450d8883-8d57c3ff]: errors:
- code: MANIFEST_EXPANSION_USER_ERROR
  message: |
    Manifest expansion encountered the following errors: Error compiling Python code: No module named googleapiclient.discovery Resource: cloudvpn-testenv.py Resource: config
```

I also tried to include the complete google-api-python-client library in my configuration yaml, but I still get this error.

Any idea someone?

Comment: Saw this in the docs: "Do not use system calls in your template. If a template contains any code that makes system or network calls, it is rejected. This includes any method that performs system calls using the supported libraries listed above." - https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/import-python-libraries

Comment: So... there is no way to get KMS secrets from deployment manager?

Comment: As far as my research went: No, I didn't find any solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:

```
# requirements.txt

google-api-python-client
```

```py
# main.py

import base64
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery

crypto_key_id = os.environ['KMS_CRYPTO_KEY_ID']

def decrypt(client, s):
    response = client \
        .projects() \
        .locations() \
        .keyRings() \
        .cryptoKeys() \
        .decrypt(name=crypto_key_id, body={"ciphertext":s}) \
        .execute()

    return base64.b64decode(response['plaintext']).decode('utf-8').strip()


kms_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudkms', 'v1')

auth = decrypt(kms_client, '...ciphertext...'])
```

You can find more examples and samples [on GitHub](https://github.com/sethvargo/secrets-in-serverless).

To indirectly answer your question, you may be interested in [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) instead.